# Twitter or Facebook Like Live Status Updates On User Interface

Tags: user-interface, twitter, live-streaming, tweets

Hi fellow programmers,

I am using Twitter Streaming API to search for tweets containing specific keywords. My requirement is to build a user interface which will show the tweets to the user of my system just like Twitter i.e. in real time. As soon as a tweet is received from the streaming API i want it to be displayed on the UI without the need of manual page refresh. Any ideas how to achieve this? I want a solution which should be ASP.NET compatible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you will want to use [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr).
It is an .NET library that give you the ability to push from the server.
It uses WebSocket for compatible browsers and fallback to polling for old browsers.

You will simply have to create a hub and then call `Clients.sendMessage()`.

Comment: Excellent advise. For those you are stuck with the same problem, kindly see https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/implementing-two-way-communication-with-signalr-8358?l=DFewtjFz_3304984382 for a woderful tutorial. Thanks @Linvi.